# Regularizing covariance matrix requries relatively large value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working with Gaussian Mixture Models in Tensorflow, and am running into a problem where the Cholesky decomposition fails due to a non-positive-definite covariance matrix. My data are a number of mfcc frames, but I am getting similar failures using only `np.random.rand(10000, 16)`.

Tensorflow has a step:

```
# Small value to guarantee that covariances are invertible.
self._min_var = array_ops.diag(
    array_ops.ones(array_ops.stack([self._dimensions]))) * 1e-3
# ...
cholesky = linalg_ops.cholesky(self._covs + self._min_var)
```

However, the value `1e-3` is not high enough to stabilize the matrix. Values of `1e1` and higher do stabilize the matrix, but they skew the results so much that the optimizer quits after a single step.

So, my question: What problems does this show with my data, and is it possible to normalize my data so that the value of `1e-3` is enough to create a positive definite matrix?

Comment: I should note, I have exported the data and used the `sklearn` implementation `GaussianMixture`, and that works just fine.

Comment: What datatype are you using? One guess would be that sklearn is using 64bit floats by default whereas perhaps you are using tf.float32 in tensorflow?

Comment: Yes, the tensorflow model uses `tf.float32`.

Comment: Try out `tf.float64` and see if it changes things.

Comment: Hm. This doesn't seem to compile (at least, not without changing a ton of tensorflow internal operations). And, in fact, I was loading in the same `float32` array to sklearn, so unless sklearn was upsampling (which I don't believe it does), the `float32` should work just fine. `ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float64 for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("sub_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)'`